# how do i use nested for loops for two dimentional arrays? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
   
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int NUM_ROWS = 5;
    const int NUM_COLS = 10;
    int array[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS]{};
    cout << "Array contents:" << endl;
    for (int row = 0;row<NUM_ROWS;row++)
    {
        for (int col=0;col<NUM_COLS;col++)
        { 
            int array[row][col] = rand () % 200;
            cout << array[row][col] << setw(2);
        }
    } 
}
```

`I want to input a random number between 0-199 by using 5 rows and 10 columns (leaving with a total of 50 values with random numbers) but my ide is registering int values: row and col as regular variables which i thought it was possible to iterate the dimensions of the array.'

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using "C" style arrays have a look at C++'s arrays (and range based for loops)

```
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

//using namespace std; // no do not us this

int main()
{
    // C++ random generation
    std::random_device entropy_source{};
    std::mt19937 random_generator{ entropy_source() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution{ 0,199 };

    //C++ 2D array 
    // with C++ arrays you can pass them around like objects
    // and return them from functions (instead of using raw pointers 
    // and running into "C" style pointer decay and memory allocation unclarities)
    std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 5> values;

    //C++ arrays keep track of their own size of use later
    std::cout << "number of rows = " << values.size() <<"\n";

    // prefer range based for loops, they cannot go out of bounds
    for (auto& row : values)
    {
        for (auto& value : row)
        {
            value = distribution(random_generator);
            std::cout << value << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should also point out the mistake OP made. They can make the same with a `std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 5>`

Comment: Fair enough ;)  But at least he couldn't write ` int array[row][col] = rand () % 200;` because there is only `value` to assign to

Comment: `int value = rand() % 200;`  ;)

Comment: Nope ;)  For example https://godbolt.org/z/9sf9EPx5c (error: redeclaration of 'int value'x86-64 gcc 13.2 #1). And for other compilers/version always compile with all warnings enabled.

Comment: sure its an error, just like OPs code has an error (but they didnt understand the error message thats why the question)

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
int array[row][col] = rand () % 200;
```

is invalid syntax. The leading `int` makes it a declaration of a new local variable `array` (shadowing the outer declaration from the third line of `main()`), but the initializer `rand() % 200` is invalid for initializing an array, so you will get a compiler error.

Drop the leading `int` to turn this declaration into an assignment and the program will compile:

```
array[row][col] = rand () % 200;
```

Comment: It's also invalid because the array dimensions aren't compile-time constants.